# Aggregate a table using a function that takes a table as a parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 3 columns ( ID , Date, Value). And a function which takes a user defined table type of (Date, Value) and returns a scalar.

How can I aggregate the table into (ID, function_result) grouping by ID?

I tried breaking it up into a subquery, but I can't think how to aggregate the two columns into a table type.

Example table:

| ID | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 31/12/2022 | -98 |
| A | 31/01/2023 | 0.166666667 |
| A | 28/02/2023 | 0.155944444 |
| A | 31/03/2023 | 0.173055634 |
| A | 30/04/2023 | 0.167905834 |
| A | 31/08/2024 | 0.174749476 |
| A | 30/09/2024 | 0.17518635 |
| A | 31/10/2024 | 0.175624316 |
| A | 30/11/2024 | 0.176063377 |
| A | 31/12/2024 | 114.2795288 |
| B | 31/12/2022 | -98 |
| B | 31/01/2023 | 0.166666667 |
| B | 28/02/2023 | 0.155944444 |
| B | 31/03/2023 | 0.173055634 |
| B | 30/04/2023 | 0.167905834 |
| B | 31/05/2023 | 0.168325598 |
| B | 31/07/2024 | 0.174313692 |
| B | 31/08/2024 | 0.174749476 |
| B | 30/09/2024 | 0.17518635 |
| B | 31/10/2024 | 0.175624316 |
| B | 30/11/2024 | 0.176063377 |
| B | 31/12/2024 | 114.2795288 |

Desired Output:

| ID | XIRR |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0.08673649 |
| B | 0.08849615 |

Function Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [RE].[XIRR]
(
    @Sample XIRRTable READONLY,
    @Rate DECIMAL(19, 9) = 0.1
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(38, 9)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @X DECIMAL(19, 9) = 0.0,
    @X0 DECIMAL(19, 9) = 0.1,
    @f DECIMAL(19, 9) = 0.0,
    @fbar DECIMAL(19, 9) = 0.0,
    @i TINYINT = 0,
    @found TINYINT = 0

IF @Rate IS NULL
    SET @Rate = 0.1

SET @X0 = @Rate

WHILE @i < 500
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @f = 0.0,
            @fbar = 0.0

        SELECT      @f = @f + [Value] * POWER(1 + @X0, (-theDelta / 365.0E)),
        @fbar = @fbar - theDelta / 365.0E * [Value] * POWER(1 + @X0, (-theDelta / 365.0E - 1))
        FROM    (
                SELECT  [Value],
                    DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(date) OVER (), date) AS theDelta
                FROM    @Sample
            ) AS d

        SET @X = @X0 - @f / @fbar

        If ABS(@X - @X0) < 0.00000001
        BEGIN
           SET @found = 1
           BREAK;
        END

        SET @X0 = @X
        SET @i += 1
   END

If @found = 1
    RETURN  @X

RETURN NULL
END
GO
```

My question is; how to build the table of values to pass into your function i.e. I want to build a table for all values of ID 'A' and pass them in, then I want to do the same for 'B' etc.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your query/function. Its very hard to understand a data question from a written description alone.

Comment: Apologies, added now with markdown table.

Comment: If you want a user defined aggregate function, you might want to instead consider [CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-aggregates?view=sql-server-ver16).

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to iterate through the ID's you have and calculate a value per ID. The following framework should be enough to get you started as I don't have enough details to ensure its working.

```
-- Build a temp table to store the results with one row per Id
select Id, convert(decimal(19,9),null) as Xirr 
into #Result
from MyTable
group by Id;

declare @Id char(1), @Rate decimal(19,9) = 0.1;

declare @InputTable XIRRTable;

-- Loop through the results table while there is still a null value
while exists (select 1 from #Result where Xirr is null) begin
    select top 1 @Id = Id from #Result where Xirr is null;

    -- Pull the values for the current id into the table variable to pass to the function
    insert into @InputTable ([date], [value])
    select [date], [value]
    from MyTable
    where Id = @Id;

    -- Update the value in the results table
    update #Result set
        Xirr = RE.XIRR(@InputTable, @Rate)
    where Id = @Id;

    -- Clear the input table ready for the next run
    delete from @InputTable;
end;

select * from #Result;

drop table #Result;
```

Comment: Thanks Dale, this style approach has worked. I tried using cross apply to nest a function that got the table of data, and a scalar valued function to calc the IRR - but this doesnt work.

Comment: @MongooseC I don't believe there is anyway to do this without a loop - one of those rare cases in SQL :)